# Method for comparing multiple continually generated arrays?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, comparison, generator

I'm currently working on a script to generate daily fantasy baseball lineups based on my own projections. The goal is to write a script that would maximize value across multiple positions within a salary constraint.

I'm a data analyst by trade, but not an experienced programmer. The approach that I've been taking is to have the script compare multiple arrays that would take the next highest player at each position until the salary requirement is met and the projected value is as high as possible. What I've realized is that this will require generating a large number of arrays since each new array will need more versions of itself generated and compared for maximum value if the first set does not meet the requirement.

I've struggled with how to properly word this question (I hope I've done a good enough job here) which has made it difficult to research if there are methods of doing something like this. I was hoping somebody may be able to point me the direction of some reading material explaining a method of doing something similar to what I described above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add some sample data?

Comment: first, select in what programming language you want to work with, Python and Javascript are too different things. Second it will be hard to point you to a correct direction if we don't even know what is your starting point, please read [mre]. hope it helps.

Comment: Try to clearly define what you are trying to achieve rather than how to do it. Once you are able to clearly articulate the problem, it will be much easier for people to help.

Comment: "The goal is to write a script that would maximize value across multiple positions within a salary constraint." is far too vague for anyone here but you to understand.

Comment: Example: "From a pool of positions with bounded salary ranges, select the position with the highest valuation". I think that you want something like this, but this is still too vague.